# Specify citation style in footnotes (point at the end of the citation)

Tags: biblatex, csquotes, biblatex-chicago

I'm trying to modify the style of citations in footnotes, specifically adding a point at the end of the citation.

I use the `biblatex-chicago` package for my bibliography and here is a MWE of my document setup:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[main=british, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
            bibencoding=inputenc,
            notes,
            isbn=false,
            noibid=true,
            doi=only,
            ]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{url,
  url = {http://www.example.de},
  author = {Surname, Prename},
  title = {An article which has a URL},
  journaltitle = {Bibliography Styles in LaTeX},
  date = {2017}
}

@article{no_url_1,
  author = {Surname, Prename},
  title = {An article which has no URL},
  journaltitle = {Bibliography Styles in LaTeX},
  date = {2017}
}

@article{no_url_2,
  author = {Surname, Prename},
  title = {An article which has no URL},
  journaltitle = {Bibliography Styles in LaTeX},
  date = {2017}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}


\begin{document}
Entry with url.\footnote{\cite{url}}
Entry without url.\footnote{\cite{no_url_1}}
Entry without url but page reference.\footnote{\cite[5]{no_url_2}}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

I made the distinction between to entries with and without url because you can see the trailing comma in the second entry. Also I created two bib entries with no url because after I reference an entry the first time, there will be a short version in the footnote.

My goal would be to have a point at the end of each footnote citation and therefore replace the trailing comma as well.
Is there a way to change the style and do this programatically (without having to write the style by myself) or do I have to insert the point manually on each entry like this:

```
\footnote{\cite{id}.}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

**[Edit]**

The given document is in a fairly final stage and I'm trying to consult with the author to fix some problems. There are quite a few long footnotes with many `cite`s in it mixed up with text. So, changing the command like @gusbrs suggested would be very hard (although possible).
I'm still hoping there is another way.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the available `\footcite{bibkey}`?

Comment: @gusbrs I should've mentioned that the text is fairly large and changing the used commands would end in quite a time consuming task (edited my question). But still thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the best solution would be to use `\footcite`.

But we can also let `\cite` end with a full stop if it is called in a footnote.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}\iffootnote{\addperiod}{}}
```

The problematic comma in the second footnote is caused by commas in `cjournal+issue+year+pages` that don't use `\setunit`.

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cjournal+issue+year+pages}{%
  \usebibmacro{cjournal+ser+vol+num}%
  \ifboolexpr{% 16th ed.
    test {\iffieldundef{issue}}%
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{year}}%
    and
    not togl {cms@switchdates}%
  }%
  {\iffieldundef{number}%
    {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{pagination}\AND%
        \iffieldundef{bookpagination}}%
      {\setunit{\postvolpunct}}%
      {\setunit{\addcolon\addspace}}}%
    {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}}%<--- HERE
  {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{volume}\AND\iffieldundef{number}}% 16th ed.
    {\newcunit%
      \iffieldundef{issue}%
      {\usebibmacro{number+or+month}}%
      {\printfield{issue}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{cmsyear}}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}%<--- HERE
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
    \printtext[parens]{% parens is the default here
      \iffieldundef{issue}%
      {\usebibmacro{number+or+month}}%
      {\printfield{issue}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{cmsyear}}}}}}
\makeatother
```

The two changes are marked with `HERE`.

Comment: (+1) There was no way I could to find where that comma was coming from!

Comment: @gusbrs The `biblatex-chicago` code is quite full-on at times.

Comment: Thanks @moewe! This is what I was looking for. And yes `footcite` would be my preferred way, too. But I hope that your answer comes with less overhead in this particular case.